# AFNetworking [NSNull length]

Tags: objective-c, json, uitableview, afnetworking

I'm getting a crash in my app with this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1cb8068'
```

I have a lot of data I need to display in my table.

In this example, I am working with the key, brands, in my JSON.

If I NSLog the brands I will get something like this:

Brand A

Brand B

Brand C

null

Brand E

null

null

Brand Z

When I scroll through my table and I hit a  the app crashes.

How can I replace the  with a string?

Here's my method:

```
- (void)updateData
{
     AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
     [manager GET:@"http://mydataurl.com/abc" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSArray * aArray = [responseObject valueForKeyPath:@"result_payload.items"];

        self.inventoryArray = [NSArray arrayWithArray:aArray];

        // ***** Brand ******
        self.brandArray = [self.inventoryArray valueForKeyPath:@"brand"];

        for (int a = 0; a < [self.brandArray count]; a++)
        {
            self.brandString = [self.brandArray objectAtIndex:a];
        }

        [self.tableView reloadData];
     }
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

}];
```

I have added a category for NSDictionary:

.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSDictionary (Utility)

- (NSString*)stringForKey:(id)key;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "NSDictionary+Utility.h"

@implementation NSDictionary (Utility)

- (NSString*)stringForKey:(id)key
{
    NSString * string = [self objectForKey:key];

    if ([string isEqual:[NSNull null]])
    {
        return nil;
    }

    return string;
}

@end
```

I haven't used categories much, do I need to call this method in a specific place? Or just add the #import to my main class?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the JSON is not returning an element with a "null" value?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the actual JSON document that the server gives you, you will find that it contains "null" values. When there is a "null" value in the data, JSON parsers will produce the value [NSNull null] to represent the null.

You have to check for that value. If you think you've got an NSString, or an NSNumber, or an NSArray or an NSDictionary but what you really have is an [NSNull null], and you send it a message, you will get a crash.

The easiest way to handle this: Add a category to NSDictionary with methods like

- (NSString*)stringForKey;
- (NSNumber*)numberForKey;

which calls objectForKey, checks the type of the object, and returns nil if its the wrong type.

As an example:

```
@interface NSDictionary (JSONExtensions)
- (NSString*)stringForKey:(NSString*)key;
@end

@implementation NSDictionary (JSONExtensions)
- (NSString*)stringForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    id result = [self objectForKey:key];

    if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]])
        result = [((NSNumber *) result) stringValue];
    else if (! [result isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
        result = nil;

    return result;
}
@end
```

This will return nil if the key is not present, or if the value is [NSNull null], or if the value is an array or a dictionary. It will convert a number to a string and return a string, so you are guaranteed to get nil or an NSString*. (Some servers tend to send strings consisting only of digits as numbers instead of strings). So if you want a string for the key "MyString", you write

```
NSString* myString = [myDict stringForKey:@"MyString"];
```

and you can be sure the result is nil or a string.

Comment: I do have a category created. Where is the proper place to call it?

Answer (score 0):

I use

```
- (id)objectForKeyNotNull:(id)key
{
    id object = [self objectForKey:key];
    if (object == [NSNull null])
        return nil;

    return object;
}
```

to convert the NSNull values to nil.  I add this as a category onto NSDictionary.